# How to combine operation with Functor?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I was watching [category lecture](https://goo.gl/xqD7O4)

```
def getNames(users: List[User]) {
  users.map(_.name)
}
```

and I add a log to the `users` count which is bad as it ties me up to `List`

```
def getNames(users: List[User]) {
  logger.info(users.count) // OMG tied up to List.
  users.map(_.name)
}
```

but this ties me up to `list`

so i'm using a `functor`

```
def getNames(users: A[USER], implicit functor: Functor[A]) {
  functor.map(users, u => u.name)
}
```

So I understand the importance of composability, and not adding features to a function which does not belong, what I don't understand is now that I want to add the `logging` feature  and other features (let's say obviously we do need these features...) how do I do that In the proper composability way?

Comment: The standard library doesn't provide a `Functor` type class, so it would be a good idea to indicate where yours came from. Also to be honest I don't see a lot of value in adding abstraction in this case specifically.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. You can actually log within the generalized functor method. But since you now have a functor you can't expect to use List-specific operations, like count. A functor has no notion of a size

Comment: @pagoda_5b so as you say I have abstracted away the list properties with the `functor`, then my quesiton is what is the proper (using composability as recommanded in video) way to `log` the `list.size`?

Comment: There's a `Foldable` type class in Scalaz that provides a `length`, and if you require both it and `Functor` you can accomplish what you want (but it's probably not worth it in this case).

Comment: @TravisBrown where is the declaration of the implicit instances for `Foldable`? As to know how general this solution can be made

Comment: @Jas You probably want to separate the logging aspect with an appropriate "abstraction" and the counting aspect with another one, so as to combine those separately. In any case, we can't assume that every aspect can be "abstracted" as a Functor, each behaviour has a proper general structure that category theory tries to classify, identifying its defining properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I follow what you are after (but not sure).  With that said to achieve a composable version of that code I'd do some as follows.  However, note that it may be **overkill** for this example but in order to simply express the concept I think its appropriate.

1 I'd define a Logger monad trait whose map/flatMap perform the logging.

2) Implement a ListCountLogger case class that overrides the flatMap

3) Then change the body of your function to this, where countLogger returns the monad:

```
def getNames( users: List[User]) {
    countLogger( users ).flatMap( _.name )
}
```

You would then be free to implement CountLoggers for each collection and as a result not be "tied" to a List.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer makes sense, and in any case it seems pretty far from what the OP is looking for. Maybe you could come up with a vaguely reasonable way to talk about monads where you override `flatMap` in a subclass for specific type constructors, but that's not at all standard and it's not going to fit with the explicit representation of `Functor`, etc. in the question.